# Streaming to BigQuery with Apache Beam Pipeline on SparkRunner

Tags: apache-spark, google-bigquery, spark-streaming, apache-beam

I am trying to run a simple streaming pipeline that reads from Kafka and writes to BigQuery. This pipeline cannot run in Google DataFlow as our kafka cluster is inside an internal network so I've been trying to run it on a local spark node. The pipeline runs without any errors with the DirectRunner, With the SparkRunner the pipeline works fine up until to the point where it tries to write to BigQuery, as it reads and transforms the messages from Fafka, but then it trows the following error:

```
    21/05/27 10:22:39 INFO BigQueryRowWriter: Opening TableRowWriter to gs://beam-temp/BigQueryWriteTemp/beam_bq_job_LOAD_kafkatobq/<hash>.
21/05/27 10:22:39 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 33855.0 (TID 8887)
org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.google.cloud.hadoop.gcsio.GoogleCloudStorageOptions
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException.wrap(UserCodeException.java:39)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.WriteGroupedRecordsToFiles$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:232)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.processElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:188)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.spark.translation.DoFnRunnerWithMetrics.processElement(DoFnRunnerWithMetrics.java:65)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.spark.translation.SparkProcessContext$ProcCtxtIterator.computeNext(SparkProcessContext.java:140)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.tryToComputeNext(AbstractIterator.java:141)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:136)
        at scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$JIteratorWrapper.hasNext(Wrappers.scala:42)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:462)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
        at scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$IteratorWrapper.hasNext(Wrappers.scala:30)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.spark.translation.MultiDoFnFunction.call(MultiDoFnFunction.java:128)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.spark.translation.MultiDoFnFunction.call(MultiDoFnFunction.java:63)
        at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$$anonfun$fn$7$1.apply(JavaRDDLike.scala:186)
        at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$$anonfun$fn$7$1.apply(JavaRDDLike.scala:186)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:823)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:823)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:346)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:310)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:346)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:310)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:346)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:310)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:346)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:310)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:346)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:310)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:346)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:310)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:55)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:411)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:417)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.google.cloud.hadoop.gcsio.GoogleCloudStorageOptions
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.util.GcsUtil.<init>(GcsUtil.java:197)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.util.GcsUtil.<init>(GcsUtil.java:88)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.util.GcsUtil$GcsUtilFactory.create(GcsUtil.java:110)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.util.GcsUtil$GcsUtilFactory.create(GcsUtil.java:93)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.ProxyInvocationHandler.returnDefaultHelper(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:605)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.ProxyInvocationHandler.getDefault(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:546)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:171)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy33.getGcsUtil(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.storage.GcsFileSystem.create(GcsFileSystem.java:135)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.storage.GcsFileSystem.create(GcsFileSystem.java:61)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileSystems.create(FileSystems.java:243)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileSystems.create(FileSystems.java:230)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryRowWriter.<init>(BigQueryRowWriter.java:58)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.TableRowWriter.<init>(TableRowWriter.java:35)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.RowWriterFactory$TableRowWriterFactory.createRowWriter(RowWriterFactory.java:83)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.WriteGroupedRecordsToFiles.processElement(WriteGroupedRecordsToFiles.java:58)
```

I run it with:

```
spark-submit --supervise --driver-cores 4 --driver-memory 15G --class org.exmaple.pipeline.KafkaToBq --master local[4] pipeline.kafkaToBq-1.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar --runner=SparkRunner
```

I suspect it might be a bad spark configuration or another dependency conflict between spark and beam, as i had one with jackson and guava too.
My dependencies in the pom tree are:

```
<properties>
        <beam.version>2.28.0</beam.version>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <gson.version>2.8.6</gson.version>
        <jackson.version>2.9.8</jackson.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.6.1</slf4j.version>
        <spark.version>2.4.7</spark.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>25.1-jre</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-scala_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Beam -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
            <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-core</artifactId>
            <version>${beam.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
            <artifactId>beam-runners-direct-java</artifactId>
            <version>${beam.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
            <artifactId>beam-runners-spark</artifactId>
            <version>${beam.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Beam Connectors -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
            <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-io-kafka</artifactId>
            <version>${beam.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
            <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-io-google-cloud-platform</artifactId>
            <version>${beam.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
            <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-extensions-google-cloud-platform-core</artifactId>
            <version>${beam.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud.bigdataoss</groupId>
            <artifactId>gcsio</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.14.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.20</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                    <filters>
                        <filter>
                            <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </filter>
                    </filters>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                            <shadedClassifierName>shaded</shadedClassifierName>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
                            </transformers>
                            <relocations>
                                <relocation>
                                    <pattern>com.fasterxml.jackson</pattern>
                                    <shadedPattern>noc.com.fasterxml.jackson</shadedPattern>
                                </relocation>
                            </relocations>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```